# Zoho Invoice API not working

Tags: zoho

I am trying three Zoho Invoice API's but they are not working.

The Invoice API's are:

1. List Contacts(Get Method)
2. List Customer Payments(Get Method)
3. Create a Customer Payment(Post Method)
4. List Contacts(Get Method)

For List Contacts I have used the url as
https://invoice.zoho.com/api/contacts/?authtoken=&scope=invoiceapi

but my response is

```
<Response status="0">
<Code>5</Code>
<Message>
<![CDATA[ Invalid URL Passed ]]>
</Message>
</Response>
```

1. List Customer Payments(Get Method)

For List Customer Payments I have used URL as

https://invoice.zoho.com/api/customerpayments?authtoken=&scope=invoiceapi

My response is

```
<Response status="0">
<Code>5</Code>
<Message>
<![CDATA[ Invalid URL Passed ]]>
</Message>
</Response>
```

1. Create a Customer Payment(Post Method)

To create a customer Payment I am using create map fields and Post URL method like below

```
<%{
map1 = map();
    map1.put("date", "2014-3-24");
    map1.put("amount", "10100");
    map1.put("customer_id", "<my custome ID>");
    map1.put("invoice_id", "<my Invoice ID>");
    map1.put("authtoken", "<my authtoken>");
    map1.put("scope", "invoiceapi");
    post = postUrl("https://invoice.zoho.com/api/customerpayments", map1,false);
    PostResponseCode=post.get("responseCode");
    PostResponseText=post.get("responseText");%>
    <%=PostResponseCode%><br/>
    <%=PostResponseText%>
<%}%>
```

but my Response is

500
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request

Can anyone please help me with this

Answer (score 3):

This is Reshma from Zoho Invoice Team. We recently launched our **REST API for Zoho Invoice and Zoho Books**. What I would suggest you to do is , include the tag V3 in your URL so the api call looks like the one shown below:

```
https://invoice.zoho.com/api/v3/entity_name?authtoken=*************&organization_id=******
```

You'll find answers to most of your questions on our API documentation [here](https://www.zoho.com/invoice/api/v3/) . Also you can always reach us out at `support@zohoinvoice.com`

Let me know if this worked out for you.

Regards,
Reshma

Comment: I tried 1. List Contacts(Get Method)
2.List Customer Payments(Get Method) but when I am trying create Payments method(post Method) it is not working proprly. My Response for post method is -{400
The request had bad syntax or was inherently impossible to be satisfied}.

Comment: Reshma, I have the same problem. The List Contacts method is not working (GET method). Seems your API has issues?

Comment: @user3332384 and VanacK Sorry about that. I have updated the URL. Please take a look again. You can also refer our API documentation here for more information https://www.zoho.com/invoice/api/v3/